# Symfony 2.7 choice form element duplicate label error

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Setting a choice element up with an array of options for the choices, the value '6 Door' appears 3 times.  In the array the keys are preserved, in the symfony generated element, the last key overwrites all the previous ones where values match.

Am I overlooking something simple?

The form element is as such:

```
->add('category', 'choice', array(
    'required' => false,
    'choices' => $this->form_repository->getOptionsForSelect(),
));

    // configure data_class
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => '\AppBundle\Model\DirectorySearch'
            ));
    }
```

form_repository::getOptionsForSelect()

```
function(){
    $q = ...
    $results = $q->getQuery()->getResult();

    $return = array();
    foreach($results as $form) {
        foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
            $options = array();

            foreach($element->getMultiOptions() as $multi_option) {
                $options[$multi_option->getId()] = $multi_option->getLabel();
            }
            $return[$element->getLabel()] = $options;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

The array returned by getOptionsForSelect:

```
array (size=3)
  'Car Brand' => 
    array (size=4)
      221 => string '6 Door' (length=6)
      222 => string 'Toyota' (length=6)
      223 => string 'Jaguar' (length=6)
      224 => string 'Skodai' (length=6)
  'Car Doors Count' => 
    array (size=2)
      226 => string '6 Door' (length=6)
      227 => string 'Green' (length=5)
  'Car Doors' => 
    array (size=5)
      228 => string '1 Door' (length=6)
      229 => string '2 Door' (length=6)
      230 => string '3 Door' (length=6)
      231 => string '4 Door' (length=6)
      232 => string '6 Door' (length=6)
```

The Select generated - noticed all 6 door labels now use value = 232:

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Car Brand">
        <option value="232">6 Door</option>
        <option value="222">Toyota</option>
        <option value="223">Jaguar</option>
        <option value="224">Skodai</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Car Doors Count">
        <option value="232">6 Door</option>
        <option value="227">Green</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Car Doors">
        <option value="228">1 Door</option>
        <option value="229">2 Door</option>
        <option value="230">3 Door</option>
        <option value="231">4 Door</option>
        <option value="232">6 Door</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I've noticed if in the form I dump `$builder->get('category')->getOptions()`
The 'choices' key shows the array above, choice list shows this, missing all duplicate labelled options.

```
'choice_list' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayKeyChoiceList)[1208]
      private 'useChoicesAsValues' => boolean false
      protected 'choices' => 
        array (size=9)
          '6 Door' => int 232
          'Toyota' => int 222
          'Jaguar' => int 223
          'Skodai' => int 224
          'Green' => int 227
          '1 Door' => int 228
          '2 Door' => int 229
          '3 Door' => int 230
          '4 Door' => int 231
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=9)
          '6 Door' => string '232' (length=3)
          'Toyota' => string '222' (length=3)
          'Jaguar' => string '223' (length=3)
          'Skodai' => string '224' (length=3)
          'Green' => string '227' (length=3)
          '1 Door' => string '228' (length=3)
          '2 Door' => string '229' (length=3)
          '3 Door' => string '230' (length=3)
          '4 Door' => string '231' (length=3)
      protected 'valueCallback' => 
        object(Closure)[1209]
```

The data class of the form:

```
class DirectorySearch implements Search
{
    private $keyword = '';
    private $company_name = '';
    private $stand_number = '';
    private $town_region = '';
    private $postcode = '';
    private $country = null;
    private $category = null;
    private $page = 1;

    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->keyword = isset($options['keyword']) ? $options['keyword'] : '';
        $this->company_name = isset($options['company_name']) ? $options['company_name'] : '';
        $this->stand_number = isset($options['stand_number']) ? $options['stand_number'] : '';
        $this->town_region = isset($options['town_region']) ? $options['town_region'] : '';
        $this->postcode = isset($options['postcode']) ? $options['postcode'] : '';
        $this->country = isset($options['country']) ? $options['country'] : null;
        $this->category = isset($options['category']) ? $options['category'] : null;
        $this->page = isset($options['page']) ? $options['page'] : 1;
    }

    public function getKeyword() { return $this->keyword; }
    public function setKeyword($keyword) { $this->keyword = $keyword; }
    public function getCompanyName() { return $this->company_name; }
    public function setCompanyName($company_name) { $this->company_name = $company_name; }
    public function getStandNumber() { return $this->stand_number; }
    public function setStandNumber($stand_number) { $this->stand_number = $stand_number; }
    public function getTownRegion() { return $this->town_region; }
    public function setTownRegion($town_region) { $this->town_region = $town_region; }
    public function getPostcode() { return $this->postcode; }
    public function setPostcode($postcode) { $this->postcode = $postcode; }
    public function getCountry() { return $this->country; }
    public function setCountry($country) { $this->country = $country; }
    public function getCategory() { return $this->category; }
    public function setCategory($category) { $this->category = $category; }
    public function getPage() { return $this->page; }
    public function setPage($page) { $this->page = $page; }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $data = array(
            'keyword' => $this->getKeyword(),
            'company_name' => $this->getCompanyName(),
            'stand_number' => $this->getStandNumber(),
            'town_region' => $this->getTownRegion(),
            'postcode' => $this->getPostcode(),
            'country' => $this->getCountry(),
            'category' => $this->getCategory(),
            'page' => $this->getPage(),
        );

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify the Symfony version you are using, since there are changes in ChoiceList from Symfony 2.3 and 2.7

Comment: Sorry, ill update the question, but 2.7

Comment: I've tested the array you posted here and work correctly for me. Did you removed some form options? Such as `choices_as_value`?

Comment: The only thing missing (other than the other simple text inputs) is the 'data_class'. Ill post that incase.

Comment: setting 'choices_as_values' although not what i want, does use the correct keys for the labels, no duplicate 232.

Answer (score 1):

I've digged into Symfony 2.7 source code and I can give you a good hint.

First, using array `key` in choices as the `html option value` is deprecated in symfony 2.7, so since it is giving you issue, I think you should go directly for the "correct" new way. The problem you are facing is due to some `array_flip` used internally.

As of Symfony 2.7 you can set `choices_as_value` to the field (being forward compatible with symfony 3.0) and pass an array of choices (in the meaning of your model, it could be a class sometimes) with `html label` as key.

In your case do:

```
function(){
    $q = ...
    $results = $q->getQuery()->getResult();

    $return = array();
    foreach($results as $form) {
        foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
            $options = array();

            foreach($element->getMultiOptions() as $multi_option) {
                // note this line
                $options[$multi_option->getLabel()] = (int) $multi_option->getId();
            }
            $return[$element->getLabel()] = $options;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

And you'll get the following array:

```
[
    'Car Brand' => [
        '6 Door' => 221,
        'Toyota' => 222,
        'Jaguar' => 223,
        'Skodai' => 224,
    ],
    'Car Doors Count' => [
        '6 Door' => 226,
        'Green' => 227,
    ],
    'Car Doors' => [
        '1 Door' => 228,
        '2 Door' => 229,
        '3 Door' => 230,
        '4 Door' => 231,
        '6 Door' => 232,
    ]
]
```

Group and entries feels much more consistent now. You can than use `choices_as_value`:

```
->add('category', 'choice', array(
    'required' => false,
    'choices' => $this->form_repository->getOptionsForSelect(),
    'choices_as_value' => true,
    'choice_value' => function ($currentChoice) {
        return $currentChoice;
    },
));
```

The option `choice_value` is used to override default `html option value` generation strategy with your own strategy; since you are using integers, just use the `choice` as the `html value` (if you had a class it would have be `$currentChoice->getId()` for example)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. Now to see if I can change some of my choices into entity types instead by using these choice_value and choice_label fields.

Comment: Sorry to piggy back off this question/answer - ill probably ask another question if i can't work this out before tomorrow - Using choice_value has stopped the form pre-populating using GET - have you encountered this?

Comment: The value that is read "from GET" is the value used by the form options, so the value returned by choice_value callback. Try with non duplicated entry first, the with duplicated one to debug. There may be multiple reason why it doesn't work, so maybe a new question is worth it. Feel free to ping me here.

Comment: Ah damn, looks like it is infact still causing the duplicate id values this way - but there is no population issue. However as an entity all the id's are intact but it cannot populate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521282/symfony2-7-entity-type-population-from-get