# Symfony2.7 entity type population from GET

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Can an entity type setup as shown below be populated via GET request?

Currently the entity type will not populate when the query string contains the correct key pair (*?category=232, the query string is the result of the forms submission - so the pairing is correct*), however if I setup the type to use a choice type it populates fine - I would like to keep this as an entity type.

```
->add('category', 'entity', array(
    'required' => false,
    'class' => 'AppBundle:FormElementOption',
    'choices' => $this->form_repository->getOptionsForSelectEntities($this->directory->getProject()->getId()),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_label'=>'label',
    'choice_value'=>'id',
    'group_by' => function ($currentObject) {
        return $currentObject->getFormElement()->getLabel();
    },
))
```

The form element rendered is:

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Car Brand">
        <option value="221">6 Door</option>
        <option value="222">Toyota</option>
        <option value="223">Jaguar</option>
        <option value="224">Skodai</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Car Doors Count">
        <option value="226">6 Door</option>
        <option value="227">Green</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Car Doors">
        <option value="228">1 Door</option>
        <option value="229">2 Door</option>
        <option value="230">3 Door</option>
        <option value="231">4 Door</option>
        <option value="232">6 Door</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can, but you need some more configuration "outside" of the form type. This method is perfect for "filter/search" form type, but is to be avoided for resource/entities creation.

Whenever you create a FormType instance you give it a name, say "search", the form will look into the request parameters for a parameter named 'search[category]'.

To use a "nameless" form type you should use in your controller an alternative syntax for creating the form, which is:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, new SearchType(), $search);
```

The first `null` means without name.

Also, make sure that the form option `_method` is set to `get` so that the data is searched inside the query string and not the request body (i.e. `_POST`).

Comment: I was returning null from the form::getName, is this the same behavior as createNamed(null,..), resulting in no name before the elements in html?  So instead of formname[categories], the output is simply categories

Comment: I think it probably should, but I won't recommend it since it is not even documented in `FormTypeInterface`. Use createNamed to be on the safe side. Also, make sure that `handleRequest($request)` really submit your form with `isSubmitted`; if not, check the `_method` option.

Comment: Neither way seem to rectify this.  Also I don't believe there is a problem with the submission of the form as the rest of the form works fine, and using choice field built from the array works,  its just when using entity type - I can only assume since the GET doesnt contain the entity and only the id of it. datatransformers need to be used. but since the new 'choice_label/value' introduction, I thought it would be able to populate the field using the id?  P.S. Also yes this is a filter form

Comment: Ok so I added a datatransformer to the entity type and it works.. bit annoying that you can setup the type to use anything for the labels and values - but then you need to use a datatransformer to convert that value when its incoming instead of outgoing..

Comment: Everything seems not work because you are mixing many concept which don't combine well. If you use 'choice' type, then define the 'choices' with grouped field. If you use 'entity' type DO NOT use 'choices'. Since you need a complex behaviour, look into 'choice_loader' option (to replace the datatransformer, choices, choices_as_value). Create a class which implements `ChoiceLoaderInterface` set it to `choice_loader` and you are done.